# A column definition list is required for functions returning "record" in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the Below Postgresql Function i am trying to get results from 2 different tables but it throws error ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record".Can anyone please help me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_page_record(IN _session INT) RETURNS RECORD AS
$$
DECLARE r1 RECORD;
DECLARE r2 RECORD;
DECLARE RESULT RECORD;
BEGIN
    SELECT array_agg(sq.*) AS arr INTO r1
    FROM (SELECT user_id, user_name 
          FROM "user" 
          ) sq;
    SELECT array_agg(sq.*) AS arr INTO r2
    FROM (SELECT client_id, client_name 
          FROM "clients"
          ) sq;

    SELECT r1.arr, r2.arr INTO RESULT;
    RETURN RESULT;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: SELECT r1.arr as col1, r2.arr as col2 INTO RESULT; try it

Comment: @Abihabi87 not working

Comment: @Abihabi87 i am having 2 columns in select query in 2 tables then how to return

Comment: Do you really want to return a record or you just don't know better?

Answer (score 11):

It returns a record,

so you should call the function as below,

```
select load_page_record(5);
```

The error come if you call it as a table

```
select * from load_page_record(5);
```

If you want to return a table place you query with join inside the body as follows,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_page_record1(IN _session INT) 
RETURNS TABLE (column1 integer, column2 integer) as
$BODY$

    SELECT column1, column2
    FROM
    table1 a
    join
    table2 b
    ON a.id = b.id

 $BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Can you pls tell where to place this query ? As i new to this db

Comment: This is how you should call your function to get the result. just execute it in the DB you have your function. I just input a random int as 5.

Comment: I just execute it db it works good. But where should i have to place this query.or Should i need to create another function and place this query

Comment: From where you want to get data from this function? So from that place you execute the query so it will run whatever the queries inside the function and give you the result.

Answer (score 2):

try this, procedur return table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_page_record(IN _session INT) 
RETURNS table(col1 record[],col2 record[]) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
    select
    (SELECT array_agg(sq.*)
    FROM (SELECT user_id, user_name 
          FROM "user" 
          ) sq
    ),
    (SELECT array_agg(sq.*)
    FROM (SELECT client_id, client_name 
          FROM "clients"
          ) sq
    );
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql stable;
```

edit: convert to text, try it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_page_record(IN _session INT) 
RETURNS table(col1 text,col2 text) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
    select
    (SELECT array_agg(sq.*)
    FROM (SELECT user_id, user_name 
          FROM "user" 
          ) sq
    )::text,
    (SELECT array_agg(sq.*)
    FROM (SELECT client_id, client_name 
          FROM "clients"
          ) sq
    )::text;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql stable;
```

Comment: it throws error PL/pgSQL functions cannot accept type record[]

Comment: Is it possible to have Columns with values as tables in returning

Answer (score 0):

try with text:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_page_record(IN _session INT) RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE r1 RECORD;
DECLARE r2 RECORD;
DECLARE RESULT text;
BEGIN
    SELECT array_agg(sq.*) AS arr INTO r1
    FROM (SELECT 'fdfdfd','fdfdd'
          ) sq;
    SELECT array_agg(sq.*) AS arr INTO r2
    FROM (SELECT 'dsds','sdsd' 
          ) sq;

    SELECT r1.arr, r2.arr INTO RESULT;
    RETURN RESULT;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then simply:

```
select * from load_page_record(8);
```

but I hope you are aware of the fact that this instruction `SELECT r1.arr, r2.arr INTO RESULT;` will only assign the first column to `RESULT`?

Comment: How to get column names ?